# Error when unoconv command is run as apache

Tags: php, pdf-generation, openoffice.org, shellexecute

Below is the error I am getting when `unoconv` command is run as apache, with root it works fine.

```
[root@tux1 apache]# sudo -u apache unoconv -f pdf /var/www/html/testing/example.xlsx
```

> creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   creation of executable memory area failed: Permission denied
>   Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.

Comment: This is resolved by changing  Home variable in the code

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I'm not able to solve it. Can you help me to change home variable?

Answer (score 7):

Ok this may be a stupid way to get around it but here goes...

Something in the chain of tools wants a home directory. The user for Apache doesn't have a home directory.

My Apache2 runs as `www-data`.

So:

```
mkdir /home/www-data
chown www-data:www-data /home/www-data
```

Voila! No more errors.

If I were a real geek I would fix the problem further up the tool chain but I'm not so there.

Comment: I'm using a different user and I'm getting the same error. Can you please help me?

Comment: Saved my day I was starting to despair about how to generate pdfs on the server with libreoffice headless not working without X and unoconv seemingly not working depending on user?!? Thx so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when converting .docx or .doc to HTML using unconv via PHP on Apache:

```
Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.
```

Eventually, I worked out the issue was with the www-data user not being able tom write to its home folder (in my case at `/var/www`). I fixed the permissions and the error was sorted.

Answer (score 0):

i have added .config and .cache sub-folders with www-data user permissions and kept the root on /var/www/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70891861/8187662